# jQuery .clone() and Microsoft Explorer (bug?)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am having some issues with Microsoft Explorer 6/7 and the jQuery "clone" function. The jQuery that I am using is:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#addFields').click(function() {
    var newCredit = $('#original').clone(); // create new set
    newCredit.find('input').val(''); // empty input fields
    $(this).before(newCredit); // append at the end
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="original">
  <li id="prodEnt">
    <label class="description" for="entity[]">Entity </label>
    <div>
      <input name="entity[]" class="element text medium" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
  </li>

  <li id="entFunc">
    <label class="description" for="element_5">Function </label>
    <div>
      <input name="function[]" class="element text medium" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="section_break_small"></li>
</div>
```

The Microsoft browser is unable to replicate more than one clone and does not style (CSS) the new elements.

Please advise me to an IE friendly alternative! Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to only select the first one if you've changed it to a class. Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't/shouldn't have `<li>` elements without a parent `<ul>`. Furthermore, you can't/shouldn't have `<div>` elements inside the `<li>` like you have. Finally, you have `id` attributes in the HTML that is being cloned, and this will result in duplicate elements with the same `id`. If you replace the outer `original` div and make it a `<ul>`, get rid of the id attributes and make it a `class` instead, it should be fine.

All that being said, [it does work for me on IE7](http://jsbin.com/iqude).

**EDIT**

In response to your comment:

To only select the first one, do this (assuming it has a class of `fields`):

```
$('ul.fields').eq(0).clone();
```

Comment: I have updated the code, and everything works properly, however, when I change the ul that is to be cloned to a class, they replicate exponentially. I have kept the ul that is cloned as an id, and it works in IE, even though it is not standards compliant. I am sure there is a way to have the replicated UL as a class, and only clone one, but I am not sure how to do it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks to your answer Paolo, I removed some div's IDs, changed by class=... and now this cloning thingy is working fine in IE.